# How to center row with dynamic cols using CSS

Tags: html, css, row, center

I'm trying to center a row with dynamic number of cols. I can't set margins equal to both sides using Bootstrap row and col. I can center it if I use `ul` and `li`, but when the number of "Cards" does not occupy the whole row space, the items in that row are center aligned -- I want them to be left aligned. Follow my code

```css
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Hind';
  src: url("../fonts/Hind/Hind-Regular.ttf"); }
body, nav, header, div, footer, section {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px; }

body {
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #2F2E33;
  font-family: "Hind"; }

header {
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  max-height: 90px; }
  header .main-bar {
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    background-color: #2F2E33;
    height: 50px; }
    header .main-bar h1 {
      padding: 0px;
      margin: 0px;
      color: #D7B135; }
  header .main-menu {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #D7B135; }
    header .main-menu .inline-navbar {
      margin: 0px;
      padding: 0px;
      height: 40px;
      text-align: center; }
      header .main-menu .inline-navbar li {
        display: block;
        float: left;
        height: 40px;
        padding: 0px 20px 0px 20px;
        width: 20%;
        line-height: 40px;
        color: #FFFFFF;
        cursor: pointer;
        -webkit-transition: 0.2s;
        transition: 0.2s; }
        header .main-menu .inline-navbar li:hover {
          background-color: #2F2E33;
          color: #D7B135; }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
  .main-bar {
    background-color: #D7B135; }
    .main-bar h1 {
      color: #2F2E33; } }
.profile-cardrow {
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
  text-align: center; }
  .profile-cardrow .profile-card {
    vertical-align: top;
    height: 30.0rem;
    background-color: white;
    margin: 20px;
    padding: 0px;
    min-width: 25.0rem;
    max-width: 25.0rem; }

.profile-card {
  height: 30.0rem;
  background-color: white;
  margin: 20px;
  padding: 0px;
  min-width: 25.0rem;
  max-width: 25.0rem; }

.profile-list {
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0px; }
  .profile-list .profile-item {
    padding: 0px;
    display: inline-block; }
    .profile-list .profile-item .profile-card {
      margin: 20px;
      height: 30.0rem;
      background-color: white;
      min-width: 25.0rem;
      max-width: 25.0rem;
      padding: 0px; }

footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  left: 0;
  min-height: 50px;
  background-color: #2F2E33; }

.top-navbar {
  background-color: #2F2E33;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  border-style: none;
  border-radius: 0px; }

.main-content {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  bottom: 50px;
  top: 90px;
  overflow-y: scroll; }
```

```html
<body>

        <section>
            <header>
                <div class="main-bar">
                    <h1>pros</h1>
                </div>
                <nav class="main-menu">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
                            <ul class="inline-navbar">
                                <li>Menu1</li>
                                <li>Menu2</li>
                                <li>Menu3</li>
                                <li>Menu4</li>
                                <li>Menu5</li>
                            </ul>
                        </div>
                        <div class="col-lg-6 col-md-6 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </nav>
            </header>
        </section>

        <section>
            <div class="main-content">

                <!--<div class="container-fluid">
                    <div class="row">
                        <div class="list-group">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-med-4 col-lg-2 profile-card"></div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>-->

                <!--<div class="row profile-cardrow">
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-4 col-sm-6 col-xs-12 profile-card"></div>
                </div>-->

                <ul class="profile-list">
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                    <li class="profile-item"><div class="profile-card"></div></li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </section>

        <section>
            <footer>
                <div></div>
            </footer>
        </section>

        <script src="js/jquery-3.2.0.min.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
```

That's the way it is now:
[image: now]

That's the way i want, but with equals margins om both sides
[image: want]

Comment: Only part of your CSS code is attached.

Comment: I edited and put all the contents of the css (generated by sass).

Comment: I've tried `calc()` but failed, as it only has 4 operator (`+`, `-`, `*`, `/`). It seems you need some simple javascript to make this happen.